# How to install ng2-prism with angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I try to install `ng2-prism` like this:

`ng install ng2-prism`

I get error:

> The package rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 does not satisfy its siblings'
>   peerDependencies requirements! Error: The package rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12
>   does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
>       at /home/codesave-dash/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:125:32
>       at /home/codesave-dash/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:268:7
>       at /home/codesave-dash/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:142:5
>       at /home/codesave-dash/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:263:14
>       at cb (/home/codesave-dash/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:47:24)
>       at /home/codesave-dash/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:263:14
>       at cb (/home/codesave-dash/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:47:24)
>       at /home/codesave-dash/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:263:14
>       at cb (/home/codesave-dash/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:47:24)
>       at /home/codesave-dash/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:263:14
>       at cb (/home/codesave-dash/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:47:24)
>       at /home/codesave-dash/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:263:14
>       at cb (/home/codesave-dash/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:47:24)
>       at /home/codesave-dash/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:263:14
>       at cb (/home/codesave-dash/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:47:24)
>       at /home/codesave-dash/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:263:14
>       at cb (/home/codesave-dash/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:47:24)
>       at /home/codesave-dash/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:263:14
>       at asyncMap (/home/codesave-dash/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:27:18)
>       at next (/home/codesave-dash/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:234:5)
>       at /home/codesave-dash/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:179:7
>       at LOOP (fs.js:1534:14)
>       at doNTCallback0 (node.js:419:9)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:348:13)

Anyone know how to fix it?